# How should I update an item from a vis.js timeline when the dataset is being loaded asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I have a working script that shows a vis.js timeline which is loaded and set within an ajax callback. Clicking an item on the timeline calls a jquery.ui dialog, and when the form within that dialog is submitted (via a bind function), among other things (such as an ajax call to update the core database), I also update the displayed timeline using the `dataset.update({id:itemId, ... })` mechanism. This is the heavily stripped down (for brevity) code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "ajax/ajax_shift.php",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
      container: document.getElementById("visualization"),
      groups: new vis.DataSet(),
      items: new vis.DataSet(),
      options: {
         [snip]
      }
      timeline = new vis.Timeline(shift_tl.container, shift_tl.items, shift_tl.groups, shift_tl.options);
   }
});

$("#dialog").dialog({   [snip]   });

function closeDialog() {   [snip]  };

$("#dialog").bind("updateShift",
   function() {
      var datastring = $("#update-form").serialize();
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "ajax/ajax_shift.php",
         data: datastring,
         success: function(data) {
            var iid = document.getElementById("shi_ref").value;
            var icontent =  [snip];
            var iclass =  [snip];
            var istart = document.getElementById("shi_start").value;
            var iend = document.getElementById("shi_end").value;
            if (data == "success") {
               items.update({id: iid, content: icontent, className: iclass, start: istart, end: iend}); // <---- WORKS :)
               $("#dialog").dialog("close");
            }
         }
      }
   }
)
```

This works very well, but I wanted the user to be able to change the date/time range and have the appropriate items load asynchronously as the timeline range is dragged/altered. I therefore had to create the timeline first, then load it via ajax. The problem is that the `items.update({id:itemId, ... })` mechanism stopped working following this code restructure. Initially I got a console error telling me that items.update was undefined, but that ceased when I added the object identifier thus: `shiftTL.items.update`. I have spent countless hours on this problem, and am now submitting the dialog form more directly (without the bind), but that is not making any difference to the core issue here, whatever it is. This is a stripped-down version of where I'm at. This code causes no console errors, and the timeline functions well in all other respects, it's just that the item is not updating in real-time as it does with my initial script (shown above):

```
var items;

var shift_tl = {
   container: document.getElementById("visualization"),
   groups: new vis.DataSet( [snip] ),
   items: new vis.DataSet(),
   options: {
      [snip]
   }
};
timeline = new vis.Timeline(shift_tl.container, shift_tl.items, shift_tl.groups, shift_tl.options);

$.ajax({
   url: "ajax/ajax_shift.php",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
      timeline.setOptions(shift_tl.options);
      timeline.setGroups(shift_tl.groups);
      timeline.setItems(data);
   }
});

timeline.on("rangechanged", function (properties) {
   $.ajax({
      url: "ajax/ajax_shift.php",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
         timeline.setItems(data);
      }
   });
});

$("#dialog").dialog({   [snip]   });

function closeDialog() {   [snip]  };

$("#updateForm").submit( function() {
   var datastring = $("#updateForm").serialize();
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax/ajax_shift.php",
      data: datastring,
      success: function(data) {
         var iid = updateForm.elements["shi_ref"].value;
         var icontent =  [snip];
         var iclass =  [snip];
         var istart = updateForm.elements["shi_start"].value;
         var iend = updateForm.elements["shi_end"].value;
         if (data == "success") {
            shift_tl.items.update({id: iid, content: icontent, className: iclass, start: istart, end: iend}); // <---- DOES NOT WORK :(
         }
      }
   }
   return false;
});
```

This is not an issue of scope, I think, as I am declaring `items` globally. I'm guessing that my problem lies in the way that the ajax call is kept open (he said without fully understanding this aspect of javascript). Can anyone help please? or explain what I might do in order to narrow down the problem?

Comment: A colleague has worked out what I was doing wrong, which was not populating the items correctly. By doing `timeline.setItems(data);` I was clearing the `shift_tl` object, such that the later `shift_tl.items.update()` was not affecting the timeline. The solution was to use `shift_tl.items.update()` when initially populating the timeline from within the ajax callback.

Comment: Would be very nice of you if you post your solution as an answer and further accept it. Best regards